# Concave Mesh Triangulation With Known Boundary

Tags: c#, triangulation, concave

I have a set of 3D points that (may) form a concave shape.  They are already ordered clockwise.  The resulting mesh will be (nearly) planar with some slight height adjustments.

What's the best algorithm for me to use in C# (Unity) to triangulate a mesh out of these points?

Comment: What you are looking for is Delaunay Triangulation algorithm. For unity you can use already existing implementation https://github.com/adamgit/Unity-delaunay

Comment: Doesn't Delaunay always end up convex?  Or am I misremembering?

Comment: Delaunay allows concave shapes. If I remember correctly it had to do something with comparing angles. Here's a sample http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/projektTDB/ht13/project10/Project-10-report.pdf

Comment: When u read the paper about concave delaunay triangulation it doesn't say comparing angles. It speaks about alphashapes. Care to elaborate? Am I missing it?

Answer (score 1):

I would start from [Triangle.NET](https://triangle.codeplex.com/) open source project. You may need to inherit your own Vertex type to keep the Z values (triangulation is always performed on XY plane)

Comment: Is that library usable in Unity?

Comment: It's a standalone library, you can use it any .NET project you like.